# How to get access to read user events from Google Calendar in React Native

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, google-calendar-api

I am new to mobile development, and I am trying to create a simple React-Native app in which I can ask a user for permission to read its events on Google Calendar, using the Google Calendar API.
I have been trying for over a week but cannot make it work on my own.

Does anyone know any good documentation, or any repo that talks about this in depth? Thanks

This is my current code

```
async function handleSignInWithGoogle() {
    const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@user");
    // if user is not logged in, send req to google api
    if (!user) {
      if(response?.type === "success") {
        const { accessToken } = response.authentication;
        setAccessToken(accessToken);
        await getUserInfo(accessToken)
        await getUsersCalendarList(accessToken);
      }
      
    } else { // else use already existing info
      setUserInfo(JSON.parse(user));
    }
  }
const getUsersCalendarList = async (accessToken) => {
    if (!accessToken) return
    let calendarsList = await fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/calenda/v3/users/me/calendarList', {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`},
    });
    return calendarsList.json();
    
}


const getUserInfo = async (token) => {
    if (!token) return
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me",
        {
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
        }
      );

      const user = await response.json();
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("@user", JSON.stringify(user));
      setUserInfo(user)
    } catch (error) {
      
    }
  }

return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeArea}>
      <Header />
      <Text>{JSON.stringify(userInfo, null, 2)}</Text>
      <Text>{JSON.stringify(events)}</Text>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.introText}>To get started:</Text>
        <Button title='Sign in with Google' onPress={() => promptAsync()} />
        <GoogleCalendarButton onPress={() => getUsersCalendarList()}/>
        <GmailButton onPress={handleGmailConnect} />
        <SpeechButton />
        <FlatList
          data={events}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View>
              <Text>{item.summary}</Text>
              <Text>{item.start.dateTime}</Text>
            </View>
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```